# Why is the memory created via unique_ptr not being deleted properly when reset() is called?

Tags: c++, memory, unique-ptr

I have an application that receives packets at a fast rate, and every time it receives packets, some objects are created to handle them and for the object creation I am using `std::unique_ptr`.

For some reason they don't seem to be getting cleaned up properly as I can see the memory usage of the application constantly rise.

[image]

I took a snapshot to see where the allocations are coming from and it was as expected

[image]

Here is the code that is creating these `PacketIn` and `PacketHeader` objects

```
while (!server->BufferEmpty()) {
        std::shared_ptr<Stream> inStream = std::make_shared<Stream>();
        std::vector<unsigned char> buffer = inStream->GetBuffer();

        std::size_t n = server->receive(boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
            boost::posix_time::milliseconds(-1), ec);

        if (ec)
        {
            std::cout << "Receive error: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::unique_ptr<IPacketIn> incomingPacket = std::make_unique<IPacketIn>();

            incomingPacket->ReadHeader(inStream);
            std::cout << "Received a buffer! ";
            //std::cout.write(buffer, n);
            std::cout << "\n";

            incomingPacket.reset();
        }

        ++packetsRead;

        inStream.reset();

}
```

`PacketIn`

```
class IPacketIn {
public:
    IPacketIn() {
        m_packetHeader = std::make_unique<PacketHeader>();
    }

    ~IPacketIn() {
        m_packetHeader.reset();
    }

    void ReadHeader(std::shared_ptr<Stream> stream) {
        m_packetHeader->ReadHeader(stream);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<IPacketHeader> m_packetHeader;
};
```

`PacketHeader`

```
class PacketHeader : public IPacketHeader {
public:
    PacketHeader() {

    }

    ~PacketHeader() {

    }

    void ReadHeader(std::shared_ptr<Stream> stream) override {
        //m_uuid = stream->ReadUUID(10);
        //m_timestamp = stream->ReadInt64();
        //m_packetId = stream->ReadShort();
    }

private:
    std::string m_uuid;
    //long m_timestamp;
    //unsigned short m_packetId;
```

I've stepped through the code and it seems calling reset is clearing the `unique_ptr` but is it actually deleting the memory it has created or am I missing something?

---

**Edit**

So it seems it is not related to the `unique_ptr` as I have tried swapping to using `new` and `delete` with the same issue.

What I have noticed is that the issue occurs when the `PacketHeader` class has member variables

```
std::string m_uuid;
long m_timestamp;
unsigned short m_packetId;
```

When these variables are removed, the issue no longer occurs.

I have narrowed it down to being the `std::string uuid;`. When this is present in the `PacketHeader` class it causes the memory to rise but when it is removed it is fine. Why is this?

Are these somehow not being removed when the object is destroyed?

Comment: Why do you even reset it?

Comment: You don't need to call reset - after the block ends in which the ptr is declared, it will be popped from the stack and its destructor gets called. (RAII) Does ReadHeader allocate? Furthermore, what toolchain do you use? There is probably some leak detection tool.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer Only member variables which should be cleaned up when the object is deleted and the functions in `Stream` don't currently do anything.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer I removed the `ReadHeader` call from the code so now it's just the creation of the `PacketIn` object and it's still rising. Removing this creation entirely resolves the issue.

Comment: Why not just `IPacketIn incomingPacket;`? Why allocate it on the heap?

Comment: Ah, actually, @CrisLuengo is making a damn good point. Why even use a smart pointer, you can just put it on the stack (and allocate memory inside the object, if you must). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization

Comment: With this logic `inStream` content is not modified because `buffer` is copy (or maybe move) constructed and all the received data is lost. Also it is not clear why would you use `shared_ptr` for `inStream` since ownership is not shared.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer The implementation is far from complete. I was just thinking ahead in the event that I would need to store the packets somehow. But that still doesn't explain why this is happening.

Comment: @VTT Good spot! Although I haven't got that far yet so parsing/storing the data isn't an issue at the moment.

Comment: What do you mean by *"haven't got that far yet"*? Aren't you getting that memory leak from executing this code snippet? Also i'm not sure how `ReadHeader` would work given that no input is getting to it.

Comment: @VTT I am not using the `Stream` for anything at the moment, nor modifying/reading its contents so it's pretty much unused (unfinished implementation). I am, but the _leak_ isn't coming from the copy. If I remove the creation of the *incomingPacket*, then it seems to be fine...

Comment: Why `ReadHeader` does not use `m_packetHeader`? And what happens when `m_uuid = stream->ReadUUID(10);` is executed? I suspect that either this example is too far from minimum required to demonstrate the issue or there is some sort of UB somewhere.

Comment: @VTT I have updated my OP with the missing classes. I believe I have narrowed it down to the `std::string uuid` stored inside the `PacketHeader` class. Commenting this variable out resolves the issue. Shouldn't this string be destroyed when the `PacketHeader` gets destroyed? Even when no value is assigned to the variable it seems to keep increasing the memory.

Comment: Does `IPacketHeader ` have a virtual destructor? If it does not then `std::unique_ptr<IPacketHeader>` won't be able to perform cleanup properly.

Comment: @VTT Ahh that was it! Silly mistake. Thank you so much. I'll happily accept that as the answer if you want to post one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that ownership of instances of `PacketHeader` class is held through a pointer to base class `IPacketHeader` which lacks a virtual destructor. So the `std::unique_ptr<IPacketHeader>` was unable to perform cleanup properly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is deleting the memory.

Note that neither of the calls to `reset` are needed - the destructor of the pointer is about to be called in both cases, and that will delete the memory.

Note that monitoring process memory is a very unreliable way to tell if you have a memory leak.  Up to some limit, system libraries quite often try *not* to reuse recently released memory - in order to reduce the impact of use-after-free bugs.

Try using valgrind to see if you have an *actual* memory leak.

**Edit**: [VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/vtt) has clarified that the OP *wasn't* just monitoring process memory, but using VS memory profiler (which is very similar to valgrind).

Comment: I'm currently using Windows, is valgrind not available for this platform?

Comment: Using VS memory profiler is a reliable way to detect memory leaks. Your comment is misleading in this regard.

Comment: @VTT Ah!  I didn't realize that was a graph from VS memory profiler.  I though it was from something like System Monitor (which just reports process memory).  I will update.